# Rails 7.0 application with bootstrap on development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, ruby-on-rails-7

I have created a new rails app, after that I have installed bootstrap with `cssbundling-rails`,

I am now getting an error `The asset "application.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.` In order to have the application run I need to run the following script
 `"scripts": { "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules" },`
Only  after that there is an application file created on assets/builds path.
But I don't want to run this command every time I am updating the css files, I want the server to pick those updates without running the yarn script.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

I recently ran into an issue similar to this and the source of the problem was in fact npm and yarn.

A properly configured application using `cssbundling-rails` should not need to run the command

`"scripts": { "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules" },`

to get the application to generate the `build/application.css`

### npm known issue

Check your npm version, there is [an issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/43338) if you are not using npm 7.1+ that basically prevents yarn from setting things up correctly.

Run `npm -v` and if necessary, upgrade npm with `npm install -g npm@latest`

If you had to upgrade npm, you will then need to close out your terminal and launch a new one, verify that the npm version is greater than 7.1.

After upgrading, re run `rails css:install:bootstrap`

And everything should be configured correctly.

### Bundle Watcher

From the [documentation for cssbundling-rails](https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails)
"You develop using this approach by running the bundler in watch mode in a terminal with `yarn build:css --watch` (and your Rails server in another, if you're not using something like [puma-dev](https://github.com/puma/puma-dev)). You can also use `./bin/dev`, which will start both the Rails server and the CSS build watcher (along with a JS build watcher, if you're also using `jsbundling-rails`)."

So, you can either run `yarn build:css --watch` from a separate terminal in your rails application or just use the `./bin/dev` but either way should resolve the issue you are experience.